# Copy to clipboard getdata function not working with modern browsers

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

We are facing issue with copy to clipboard function, which is working fine with IE browser while copying       data from Excel to grid on browser,but not working with modern browsers.

> Our code is using GWT and through java native method call its calling Javascript code.
> We have tool button- with name "Paste from excel"  on click of it below code gets called
>
> I was trying to use `event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain")` but in my case I am not aware how to get event in `getClipboardData()`. Please comment if any one has resolved similar issue, considering the code how I can get event(paste event) in getClipboardData() or any alternative way to get solution.

```
protected Function pasteFromExcelFunction =new Function(){
    public void execute(){
     if(readOnly){
     return;
     }// its false
    try{
         if(pasteFromExcelHelper.pasteDataIntoGrid(BaseEditorGridPanel.this, getRecordDef()));
           doAfterPaste();
   }
    }
  }    
    public boolean pasteDataIntoGrid(BaseEditorGridPanel grid, BaseGridRecordDef recordDef)
    {
      boolean pasteSuccessful=true;
      String pastedText= readFromClipboard(); 
     }   
     private String readFromClipboard (){
    return JavaScriptUtils.getClipboardData();
   }

public static native String getClipboardData()/*-{
    if($wnd.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData){
    return $wnd.clipboardData.getData('Text');
}-*/;
```

Comment: public static native String readText()/*-{
   try
     {
      var promise = $wnd.navigator.clipboard.readText();
      var resolve = function(text){
      console.log(text); 
      }
      catch (e){
      //futher code goes here
      }
     }-*/;
   above code is working, can anybody help here how to return (text) value as String

Comment: Experts could you please comment!!